# Python image processing without external libraries

Tags: python, image-processing

Im working of a project in python that is intended to be as modular and flexible as possible. The project must to be written in Python, and it involves some image processing (access to individual pixels and image size).

what would be the best way to manipulate an image in Python without the use of external libraries? I am trying to use as little dependancies as possible, so it will be easy to transfer to different platforms.

I would appreciate any other approaches that might work better.

Comment: Python has no standard way to deal with complicated files like jpg, so you would have to code all that again. Use an external library. While PIL is the most recommended it seems that it is abonded. It looks like [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1) is a working fork (have not tried it). All major OS are supported.

Comment: This might be a reasonable approach if you know beforehand that you will only ever see PGM images... But if you might see PBM, PGM, PNM, PNG, JPEG, GIF, TIFF, ...... then you really want to just use a good library that's already been written for you....

Comment: Just to add to that, even if you do write your own image readers (presumably for relatively simple formats like PNM), then performing typical image processing operations will be quite slow - tight loops are not python's strong point. You really want to use a fast library (I'm partial to NumPy) to get decent performance.

Comment: Most Python packages are relatively platform independent, so you shouldn't worry too much about being dependent on them. That said, images can look very much like a two-dimensional array; such arrays can be implemented by adding a member function to a class which takes two parameters: [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). If your code simply assumes it will get a 2D array you can make it package independent.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can understand your concern I myself had a similar problem when i did a project on image processing and i had to port it to nanoboard(FPGA) so using external  libraries is much of a headache.

What i did was, first programmed the code using the libraries at hand and then looked up for their implementation. You can view the source code for functions in python and they could be used with a little modifications. Hope it helps. Reach me for any furthur queries.